# If dark pans brown food faster, do I need to make adjustments to baking when I use a light colored pan (and vise-versa)?

Tags: baking

Would lining a dark pan with foil inhibit the browning significantly?

Comment: where do you get the notion that dark pans brown better?  I've never heard that...

Comment: do you mean in baking?  @Sam - for baking purposes glass and dark metal are considered to brown baked goods faster than light metal

Comment: I have a cake tin (dark metal) which has started to leak.  As a consequence I lined the tin with foil last time I baked a cake, and I can't say that I noticed that the cake was less brown, but there again I wasn't looking for it.  The cake was brown on the bottom though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For metal pans, lining them won't significantly affect the cooking time -- the reason they cook differently is because of how much radiant heat they reflect.  (dark absorbs, light reflects).

For a glass pan, however, I would think that if you use aluminum foil, or something light and reflective, that it could make it cook more like a light metal pan, as the issue in the glass pan is that it allows almost all of the radiant heat through without reflecting it.  I've never tested it, though.